# Como buscar un valor dentro de un objeto referenciado

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Deseo realizar una busqueda en la base de datos de mongodb, buscando por el id de un objeto referenciado. El problema que solo me busca de un total de 100 solo devuelve un array vacio [] como  resultado.

A continuacion mostrare las 2 colecciones con datos.

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
//atributos de la tabla productos
const productoSchema = new Schema({
  codigo: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 250
  },
  codOperario: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 200
  },
  descripcion: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 200
  },
  unidad: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 200
  },
  conversor: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 200
  },
  tipoConversor: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 100
  },
  imagen: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  stock: {
    type: Number
  },
  bodega: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "bodega"
  },
  precioCompra: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  precioVenta: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  ventas: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  createAt: {
    type: Number,
    default: Date.now
  },
  estado: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  eliminar: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  }
});

const Producto = mongoose.model("producto", productoSchema);

export default Producto;
```

Base de  datos de Bodega

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const bodegaSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: { type: String, maxlength: 200},
    estado: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    eliminar: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const Bodega = mongoose.model('bodega', bodegaSchema);

export default Bodega;
```

El metodo que estoy realizando la consulta de solo el valor de bodega dentro de productos es el siguiente:

```
      bodega: async(req, res, next) => {
    try {

        let valor = req.query.valor;
        const reg = await models.Producto.find({

            bodega:  new ObjectId(valor)

        }).populate('bodega', {
            nombre: 1
        }).sort({
                'createdAt': -1
            });
        res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Ocurrió un error'
        });
        next(e);
    }
},
```

Se utilizaron operador logico como $and y se obtiene el mismo resultado. Que no  encuentrar ningun  valor.

Muchas gracias

Comment: En primer lugar, no son tablas, son colecciones. En segundo lugar, dices que la consulta debe devolver 100 elementos, pero sólo devuelve 2. ¿Existen 100 documentos en tu colección `Productos`, cuyo campo `bodega` sea igual? En tercer lugar, el valor que pasas como filtro a tu consulta: `{'bodega': valor}` debe ser un objeto: `{bodega: valor}` (quita las comillas para el nombre de la propiedad, es una buena práctica). Por último, la consulta tal vez no realiza el cast de `valor` a `ObjectId`. Estarías comparando un tipo `String` con un `ObjectId`. ¿Podrías revisar estos puntos? Saludos

Comment: Hola muy buenas tardes Mauricio Contreras, agradezco los consejos y correcciones . Realizare los que me indicas y comunicare si funciona. Muchas gracias

Comment: Pido perdon la demora, pero no se obtienen los resultados, agradezco el tiempo dado muchas gracias